# Where to reliably buy Bitcoins via PaySafeCard?

Tags: paypal

Where to buy Bitcoins in a serious way via PaySafeCard? I do not like to name my account data or credit card data...

I want to use a method to buy safely and anonymously.

Comment: I do not think so since I asked for PaySafeCard as well...

Comment: @Kutsubato The PayPal part is a duplicate, the PaySafeCard not. I suggest you alter your question and only mention PaySafeCard, to make it a valid new question.

Comment: There are also ATM machines, some of them allow to buy anonymously. And there is the possibility to buy privately. Are these working options for you too?

Comment: I did so, sorry. ATM does not work for me.

Comment: Isn't paysafecard the same thing as a prepaid debit card?

Comment: As far as I know, no. It is more like a phone card but for everything.

Comment: As far as I know, no. It is more like a phone card but for everything.